# "Have completed" or "had completed"

Tags: tense, past-tense, present-perfect, past-perfect

In reality I completed my graduation in 2008.
 Which line is correct?

> I have completed graduation in 2008

or

> I had completed graduation in 2008

Comment: Occam's Razor (don't complicate things unnecessarily) applies here. Just stick to simple past *I completed graduation in 2008* and you won't have a problem. Even more straightforward, and *much* more likely, *I **graduated** in 2008*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers if i say "I graduated in  bachelor of arts in 2008". is this correct

Comment: No - that would normally be *I graduated **as a** Bachelor of Arts in 2008* (where the *as a Bachelor of Arts* bit is optional/parenthetical). In normal speech the full form is a bit stiff/formal. Most people would just use BA (pronounced Bee-Ay), and they'd probably be most likely to say *I **got my BA** in 2008* (if you want to be more formal, ***obtained** my BA*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers    I have to be formal and cant use abbreviation .I will use "I obtained  graduation as Bachelor of arts in 2008 from ABC University".Is this correct.Please tell.

Comment: There's nothing remotely "informal" about abbreviating Bachelor of Arts to BA, so you can forget that constraint. Your best bet, as per my first comment, is simply *I graduated from ABC University in 2008*. I don't think it would ever be natural to speak (or write) of *obtaining graduation*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I appreciate your  patience    Finally can i  use, "I graduated from ABC University as a Bachelor of arts in 2008 as a correspondence student,

Comment: It's a bit verbose - but yes, you could use that. Personally I'd be inclined to not mention the Bachelor of Arts bit at all (that's the lowest qualification you'd be likely to "graduate" with, so why call attention to it). And for much the same reason, I wouldn't mention the fact that it was through a correspondence course unless that was absolutely necessary (it might well not be considered as good as a degree obtained by *going to* the university).

Comment: If you are describing your accomplishments, "I earned a BA in XYZ from ABC University in 2008" might work better.  It subtly highlights the work you did to graduate.

Answer (score 1):

*I have completed graduation in 2008* is wrong.  [You can't use present perfect with specific time expressions](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentperfect.html), and "in 2008" is specific.

As @FumbleFingers says, *graduated* is a much better term here.  The above still applies.

Furthermore, note that the past perfect, versus simple perfect, is optional here for a couple of reasons (read [this](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastperfect.html).), specifically

> Unlike with the Present Perfect, it is possible to use specific time
>   words or phrases with the Past Perfect. Although this is possible, it
>   is usually not necessary.

So *I graduated in 2008* is the simplest way to say it, but *I had graduated in 2008* is not wrong.

Comment: To me, *I had graduated…* implies you're talking about two or more events in the past, for example,   *I had graduated with a bachelor's degree in 2008 when my brother got married.*  Both events were in the past, but you're emphasizing that one had already completed when the other happened.